# Integration testing for ChangeEmailAsync in .net core 3.1

Tags: asp.net-mvc, .net-core-3.1

I am trying to write Integration test case for change EmailID.

### cshtml.cs file

```
var token = await _userManager.GenerateChangeEmailTokenAsync(user, Input.Email);
var changeEmailResult = await _userManager.ChangeEmailAsync(user, Input.Email, token);

[Fact]
public async Task OnPostUpdateEmailAsync_WithValidInput_ShouldReturnSuccessMessage()
{
    await _client.LoginAsync("test1@test.com", TestData.AlicePassword);

    var response = await _client.SubmitAsync("./OnPostUpdateEmailAsync", new
        {
            Email = "testemail@test.com",
            Password_ChangeEmail = "Password1"
        });

    response.AssertOnPage("./ChangeEmailPassword/UpdateEmail");
    response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

    var document = await response.GetDocument();
    document.QuerySelectorAll(".alert-success")
        .AssertCount(1)
        .AssertHasTextEqual(
            $"The email address has been changed successfully.");
}

[Fact]
public async Task OnPostResetPasswordAsync_WithWrongConfirmPassword_ShouldReturnErrorMessage()
{
    await _client.LoginAsync(TestData.AliceEmail, TestData.AlicePassword);

    var response = await _client.SubmitAsync("./ChangeEmailPassword/OnPostResetPasswordAsync", new
        {
            OldPassword = "OldPassword1",
            Password = "NewPassword1",
            ConfirmPassword = "NewPassword1"
        });

    response.AssertOnPage("./ChangeEmailPassword/ResetPassword");
    response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

    var document = await response.GetDocument();
    document.QuerySelectorAll(".alert-danger")
        .AssertCount(1)
        .AssertHasTextEqual($"Error: The passwords do not match.");
    }
```

It is working fine but after executing this, all other test case is getting failed. As i can assume we are changing email id here but for others it still look for old email id. May be i am wrong here. Requesting you all, please help me in this.

Comment: I am writing test case in XUnit

Comment: Could you put up one of the following test cases that are failing?

Comment: public async Task method1()
{
await _client.LoginAsync(TestData.AliceEmail, TestData.AlicePassword);
var response = await _client.SubmitAsync("/Account/ChangeEmailPassword/OnPostResetPasswordAsync", new
{
OldPassword = TestData.AlicePassword,
Password = TestData.AliceNewPassword,
ConfirmPassword = "InvalidPass"
});
response.AssertOnPage("/Account/ChangeEmailPassword/ResetPassword");
response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
var document = await response.GetDocument();
document.QuerySelectorAll(".css")
.AssertCount(1)
.AssertHasTextEqual(
$"Error: The passwords do not match.");
}

Comment: Not like that.  Putting all your code in the comment removes the formatting and makes it difficult to read.  I meant for you to edit your post and add this test underneath your test above.  Could you do that please?  If you can't, I (or someone else with the authority) can do that for you.

Comment: I have updated above code @DougF

Comment: Thanks for doing that.  Let me ask, are you sure that the first test is working as it's supposed to?  The reason why I'm asking is because you're looking for an element with .alert-success in your markup, but is that class already present in your markup, but just invisible?  In other words, are you getting a false positive?

Comment: Yes, in my output it appears in HTML tag. So, I took that as reference here. Problem is, if I am running all test case individually, it's working as expected. But when I try to run all the test case at once then some of test case getting failed after execution of this test case.

Comment: What happens in debugging?

Comment: It hits my actul method and from there i have returned Page(). So, by that test case able to get that class name. On every way it's working fine if i run test case individually. Getting problem when i run whole test case at once.

Comment: Is it really possible to write Integration test case for Reset Password and Change Email address in .net core? as we are using Identity server for this

Comment: Any reason why you made these tests asynchronous?  I'm wondering if that's part of the issue.

Comment: It's resolved. I was some data related issue. It's all good. Thanks you so much!

Comment: Oh good.  If you like, maybe detail what happened in an answer post and then you can credit yourself with the answer.